# Why does the result of an outer join in SQL contain a column of null, when the original table did not?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have been playing around with the **places.sqlite** database used by Firefox to store bookmarks, among other things. Its structure is shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Database).

I would like to perform this query:

```
SELECT b.title, p.url 
FROM moz_bookmarks AS b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN moz_places AS p using(guid) 
WHERE dateAdded > 1502724919884000 
ORDER BY dateAdded 
   AND p.url like '%youtube%' 
   AND p.url NOT LIKE '%list%';
```

And I do get quite a few results, but unfortunately the whole 'url' column is filled with NULLs. Now when I do

```
SELECT url FROM moz_places;
```

the urls are shown correctly. I assume there is something about the join-functionality that I've missed, but until now I could not quite figure it out.

What I've tried so far:

- Checking this forums (didn't find anything that worked or searched the wrong things)
- changed the order of the query, which resulted in the titles column being null
- somewhat blindly trying out different joins as this was something a lot of related SO posts suggested

Right now I don't see how i can fix this problem, could someone help me with that? It would be appreciated :)

Comment: What is the `and` in the `order by` clause.  It looks wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the tables on the `guid` column, while the documentation you linked states that :

> The fk column provides the id number of the corresponding record in moz_places

So your join condition should be `moz_bookmarks.fk = moz_places.id` :

```
SELECT b.title, p.url FROM moz_bookmarks AS b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN moz_places AS p ON b.fk = p.id
ORDER BY dateAdded 
AND p.url like '%youtube%' 
AND p.url NOT LIKE '%list%';
```

Comment: Yeah, that works! Sorry for not properly reading the documentation i linked >_>